# Silverlight HyperlinkButton in DataGrid column. Have to click twice

Tags: .net, silverlight, events

I have a datagrid column that has Hyperlinkbuttons. You have to click the button twice to have the button do what it's supposed to do. I think the first click actually selects the row.

I believe something may be going on where the event doesn't bubble up (or down?) to the hyperlink button.

Ideas?

## edit

Here's the xaml:

```
    <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="workflowsGrid" Margin="6,20,6,0" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredSource,ElementName=workflowsFilter}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorkflow,Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionChanged="workflowsGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>          
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" >
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource actionConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

And here's the converter that adds the hyperlink buttons:

```
/// <summary>
/// Dynamically controls the action cell in the workflows grid
/// </summary>
protected class ActionValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private WorkflowManager _page;
    public ActionValueConverter(WorkflowManager page)
    {
        _page = page;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var workflow = (WorkflowInstance)value;
        if (workflow.Status == "Complete")
        {
            // create hyperlink buttons for each action that the workflow supports
            var btns = workflow.Definition.Actions
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    HyperlinkButton btn = new HyperlinkButton
                    {
                        Tag = Tuple.Create(workflow, x.Key),
                        Content = x.Value,
                    };
                    btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(_page.ActionButton_Click);
                    return btn;
                });

            // stack panel to contain all the buttons
            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            foreach (var btn in btns)
                sp.Children.Add(btn);

            return sp;
        }
        else if (workflow.Status == "In Progress")
        {
            // create only a cancel hyperlink button
            HyperlinkButton btnCancel = new HyperlinkButton { Content = "Cancel", Tag = Tuple.Create(workflow, "Cancel") };
            btnCancel.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(_page.ActionButton_Click);
            return btnCancel;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("workflow status not supported: " + workflow.Status);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can u post the Xaml containing the hyperlink button in the grid? It would be more helpful then.

Comment: @vaibhav - there you go.

Comment: The purpose of a converter is to convert values... not a place to hook up dynamic controls. Have you considered using behaviours instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should use the Edit template instead of the Cell template as specified in the following link:

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/132619/296134.aspx

That ways your link column will always be in Edit mode and should require only a single click.

Edit:

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate >
```

instead of

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: forums.silverlight.net link is broken, it seems all silverlight forum links are broken lately... 
please ask microsoft to fix this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightgen/thread/a7833d0d-ce77-49cc-ab05-4944cc707eef